# Handle null element in linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm reading data from an XML. I'm running into an issue where a value is null and I'm not sure the best way to handle it. Below is a snippet of code. The Street Address 2 does not exist in this XML but does in others so I need to make it dynamic enough to handle both instances.

```
var storeInfo = storeRows.Descendants("Store").Select(s => new
{
    storeName = s.Element("StoreName").Value,
    streetAddress1 = s.Element("StreetAddress1").Value,
    streetAddress2 = s.Element("StreetAddress2").Value
});
{
    foreach (var st in storeInfo)
    {
        alStoreName.Add(st.storeName.ToString());
        alStreet1.Add(st.StreetAddress1.ToString());
        alStreet2.Add(st.StreetAddress2.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use explicit cast instead of accessing `Value` property

```
var storeInfo = storeRows.Descendants("Store").Select(s => new
{
    storeName = (string)s.Element("StoreName"),
    streetAddress1 = (string)s.Element("StreetAddress1"),
    streetAddress2 = (string)s.Element("StreetAddress2")
});
```

This will return `null` if the element does not exist.

In addition I recommend you to create a `class` to encapsualate store info instead of storing information in different lists. Then just have a list of `storeInfo`'s instead of a list of anonymous type:

```
var storeInfo = storeRows.Descendants("Store").Select(s => new StoreInfo
{
    storeName = (string)s.Element("StoreName"),
    streetAddress1 = (string)s.Element("StreetAddress1"),
    streetAddress2 = (string)s.Element("StreetAddress2")
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `(string)XElement` explicit cast instead of `Value` property. It will return `null` when element doesn't exist.

```
streetAddress2 = (string)s.Element("StreetAddress2")
```

You can cast `XElement` to most of the primitive types, `string`, `DateTime`, `Guid` and `Nullable<T>` of above. See full list here: [XElement Type Conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986933(v=vs.110).aspx)

The same rule applies to `XAttribute`.